# Images same height on local (illustrator) but different sizes when loaded

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem I cannot get my head around.

I have three sets of images - these have the same height on illustrator. When I use them in the browser, they suddently have different heights and this is problematic for me.

In illustrator, my images are all 94px.

On mobile, they have different *intrinsic* heights, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is: how do I make sure these images have the same dimension?

Comment: You can set the image height statically IE `<img src="/image.svg" height-"94" width="418">`  Your SEO and Accessibility score will also benefit from doing so.

Comment: You could also paste one of the offending SVGs code here for others to look at.  --  Ultimately that will yield your best answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tried setting a height, or max-height in css ? Also make sure that they're all using the same class

Comment: You are answering the OP with a question / comment

Answer (score -1):

Since these are SVGs and you are doing it in Illustrator, check the artboards and the object heights.

Do the artboards all have the same height? I would say no because the top and bottom of STING are chopped off a bit. It seems like the artboard is smaller than the object.